# .then() is not function in node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm new to node.js. I trying to use express to customize the payload and response. But when I calling the api it shows .then() is not a function

**ExpressHandler.ts**

```
import httpStatus from 'http-status'



export const ExpressHandler = (controller) =>{
    return (req, res, next)=>{
        const httpRequest = {
            body: req.body,
            query: req.query,
            params: req.params,
            ip: req.ip,
            method: req.method,
            files: req.files,
            file: req.file,
            path: req.path,
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': req.get('Content-Type'),
              Referer: req.get('referer'),
              'User-Agent': req.get('User-Agent')
            }
          }
          controller(httpRequest)
          .then((responseObj) => {
            return res.send(responseObj)
          })
          .catch((err) => {
        console.log('>>>>ERROR>>>>\n\n\n\n\n',err,'\n\n\n\n\n<<<<<ERROR<<<<<')
        const errorMessage =
          typeof err.errorResponse !== 'undefined' ? err.errorResponse : err
        console.log('<<<ruleServiceConfig>>>==>\n\n\n\n',errorMessage,'\n\n\n\n<<<ruleServiceConfig>>>==>')
        const apiErr = new Error(
            errorMessage,
            // typeof err.resType !== 'undefined' ? err.resType : 'error',
            // typeof err.status !== 'undefined'
            //   ? err.status
            //   : httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            // typeof err.isPublic !== 'undefined' ? err.isPublic : true
        )
        next(apiErr)
      })
    }

}
```

Error I got is

```
TypeError: controller(...).then is not a function
    at ExpressHandler (D:\Learning\NodeSign\src\Config\ExpressHandler\index.ts:24:10)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Learning\NodeSign\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\Learning\NodeSign\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\Learning\NodeSign\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Learning\NodeSign\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\Learning\NodeSign\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (D:\Learning\NodeSign\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\Learning\NodeSign\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (D:\Learning\NodeSign\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Learning\NodeSign\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\Learning\NodeSign\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at D:\Learning\NodeSign\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (D:\Learning\NodeSign\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\Learning\NodeSign\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at query (D:\Learning\NodeSign\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\query.js:45:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Learning\NodeSign\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

route is below

```
import express from 'express'
import {ExpressHandler} from '../Config/ExpressHandler'
import SignUp from '../Controllers/User/SignUp'

const UserRoute = express()
UserRoute.get("/SignUp",ExpressHandler(SignUp))
export default UserRoute
```

```
import {UserContainer} from '../../Config/ioc'
import {IUserService} from '../../Service/User/IUserService'

export const SignUp = (httpRequest) => {
    const userService = UserContainer.get<IUserService>(
        Symbol.for('IUserService')
      ) 
    return userService.SignUp(httpRequest.body)
}
```

I have updated the question. This is my controller layer
what's going wrong with is . I tried still not able find out this

Thanks advance !!

Comment: Where is `SignUp` defined? `.then` can only be applied to promises. SignUp is probably not returning a promise

Comment: please paste the code inside '../../Config/ioc'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SignUp function should return the promise. Add promise to your function like so

```
import {UserContainer} from '../../Config/ioc'
import {IUserService} from '../../Service/User/IUserService'

export const SignUp = async (httpRequest) => {
    const userService = UserContainer.get<IUserService>(
        Symbol.for('IUserService')
      ) 
    return  await userService.SignUp(httpRequest.body)
}
```

Comment: This is a very bad practice. Using `return await` is meaningless in async functions and slows your code down (adds an extra layer of promises to resolve). Also, if it didn't return a promise before, SignUp is not asynchronous, and that `await` is meaningless